# upcast from indirect multiple inheritance of a base

Tags: c++, oop, multiple-inheritance

I have this code:

```
struct A {};
struct B : A {};
struct C : A {};
struct D : B, C {};

int main(){
    D* d;
    A* a = d;
}
```

The code doesn't compile and I get a compile error:

> 'A' is an ambiguous base of 'D'

I know that making the inheritance virtual will solve the ambiguity. My question is, why doesn't the upcast work to one of the sub-objects of A ?

Comment: "to one of the sub-objects of A" To which one?

Comment: @n.m. either one?

Comment: So you wouldn't care about the behaviour that follows?

Comment: Great idea. Let's eliminate all ambiguities by forcing the compiler to silently make an arbitrary choice. Programmers will *love* it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have two distinct base subobjects of type `A`, you need to say which one you want:

```
A* a_b = static_cast<B*>(d);
A* a_c = static_cast<C*>(d);
```

Comment: but this is from B to A (or C to A). I'm asking about D to A

Comment: @Loay: Read it again carefully. We *are* converting from D to A. Just in two steps.

Comment: you're right I didn't pay attention, my bad. I thought the whole upcast isn't possible unless the inheritance is virtual, thanks! :)

Comment: is there a way to upcast from D to A in one step? instead of casting to B* then to A*.

Comment: @Loay: The question doesn't make sense. `D` and `A` are types. You don't cast types, you cast *values*.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are dealing with multiple inheritance, you have to cast between one of the superclasses of the class `D`, like this:

```
struct A {};
struct B : A {};
struct C : A {};
struct D : B, C {};

int main(){
    D* d;
    A* a = static_cast<B*>(d);
}
```

You could also cast into a `C*`, but it would be of no major difference, in this scenario, since all the classes are empty.

Comment: How exactly would it not be a "major difference"?! You end up pointing at a *different object*.

Comment: I meant in this specific case, where the classes have no body, of course when the bodies of the function differ, as common, then you would have to choose

Comment: Even if the class `A` is empty, the two subobjects are different objects. For example, they have different addresses. If you used the address of the object as a key somewhere, this would be important.

Comment: @KerrekSB I repeat again , **Not in this scenario**

Answer (score -2):

This is because the compiler can not determine the true base class (from B or from C).

When you use this hierarchy, you are actually using the two instance of class A. One instance is contained in the class B, the other in class C. To use a single instance, use a **virtual base class**. [Virtual inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance)

```
struct A { };
struct B : virtual A { };
struct C : virtual A { };
struct D : B, C { };

int main(){

    D* d;
    A* a = d;
}
```

Comment: What's a "true base class"? Is there any other class?

Comment: @KerrekSB, Class D contains two class A instances (one in class B, and other in class C). If you try to cast pointer to D to pointer to A, you can not explicitly define the desired (true) instance of class A.

Comment: Ah, so now you're talking about *instances*, not classes. That makes somehwhat more sense. I'm still not entirely sold on your identification of "true" with "desired", though. Note that we don't actually *know* the OP's desire, because the code is ambiguous.